# unable to make Elastic Load Balancer work on port 8080

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, elastic-load-balancer

My EC2 instance has a site hosted using tomcat and that can be accessed using

```
http://public-Ip:8080/index.html
```

But when i put this instance behind a elastic load balancer, set the health check to

```
HTTP:8080/index.html
```

though the ELB passes the health check, when i try to access the using site using

```
 http://ELB:8080/index.html
```

i am unable to access the site.

Is there something that is missing? or i need to do additionally.

This is how my LB listner tab looks like

[LB listner tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vS6.png)

Comment: When you configured your load balancer, did you set up a listener on port 8080? And are you sure that's what you want to do? I would imagine that you'd want your load balancer to listen on port 80, but then connect to your instance on 8080.

Comment: @Brian yes i want my LB to open with the DNS provided ie on port 80 but listen to the instance's 8080 port. so what additional configuration change i need to do

Comment: You should be all set then - just connect to `http://ELB:80/index.html` (or `http://ELB/index.html` for short...)  If it's not working, then please show your ELB settings (specifically the "Listeners" tab).

Comment: @Brian added the shot of the listener tab

Comment: Did you enable port 8080 in the load balancer's security group Inbound rule?

Comment: @JohnHanley all port traffic is enabled in that SG, do i need to keep the source as the SG of the instance?

Comment: Only enable ports that your load balancer listens on in the load balancers security group. I think, but I am not sure, that this will reduce the load balancer bandwidth that you pay for. For your EC2 instances, you only want to accept traffic from the load balancer (plus your remote management (RDP / SSH) port). Add the load balancers security group as the source for the listening ports in your Inbound security group.

Answer (score 1):

There was issue with the communication between the Security Group  (SG) of my EC2 instances and the Elactic Load balancer(ELB) SG. I allowed my EC2 SG in the ELB SG and that helped.